# PIL's Image.show() brings up *two* different viewers

Tags: python, linux, python-imaging-library

When toying with images in the python shell, I use image.show(), where image is an instance of Image.  Long ago nothing happened, but after defining a symlink to mirage named "xv", I was happy.

The last few days, show() will bring up both ImageMagick's display and also Mirage.  It's not clear where show() gets information on what to run.  Documentation wasn't helpful.  How to make it behave and bring up only what it thinks is xv?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a Python question and not a Linux question?  
   The documentation at http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm   says that Image.Show() _*always*_ invokes `xv`.     But I am fairly certain that you have set Mirage as your default image vier for that type of image (.jpg or whatever). I am still baffled, though, as to why is is displayed twice. Could you post some code?

Comment: I assume it's something inside the guts of the show() function.  Could be wrong.  If there's something haywire in some unixy-style .*rc file, I'm more interested in how PIL's functions relate to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for one thing, im.show is only intended for debugging purpose, it isn't guaranteed to work.

Nevertheless, you can always look at the source (open "pydoc PIL", the FILE section points out where a module is located):

In Windows, PIL will use "start /wait filename"

In Macs, it uses "open -a /Applications/Preview.app"

and on Linux, either 'display' if found or otherwise 'xdg-open'.

Comment: The fun part is figuring out why *two* apps get started.  The source shows several lines like "if blah-blah-app exists, register it as a viewer" with no "else" separating them. Multiple viewing apps are put in a list and each is invoked.  Odd design!  I have display and mirage in /usr/bin but didn't have trouble because, I now realize, I haven't done much with PIL since months ago.

Comment: Yes, please look at ImageShow.py. The show() function will go through the list of registered viewers, and run them one-by-one. A proper registered viewers must return True when its viewer.show() is called, since that signals ImageShow's show() to stop trying other viewers. One of your registered viewers must be succeeded in showing the image but returns False, which causes PIL to try another viewer.

Answer (score 5):

A little out-off-dated but...
I solved this problem changing the code of file `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageShow.py`. Is missing a `return` on method `show` of `Viewer` class (near line 66): `return self.show_image(image, **options)`.

Answer (score 1):

A sort of a workaround I found.

I used:

```
image.save('something.png')
```

Opened the png from the file manager using the default preview program.
Then every time I called `save` again, the previewer automatically refreshed, and I got the new image :)

Answer (score 1):

`ImageShow` has a list of supported and available viewers in `ImageShow._viewers`. On my box, two viewers are found:

```
>>> import PIL.ImageShow
>>> PIL.ImageShow._viewers
[<PIL.ImageShow.DisplayViewer instance at 0x2587ef0>, <PIL.ImageShow.XVViewer instance at 0x2587f80>]
```

Unfortunately `ImageShow.show()` uses all available viewers. Thus two windows are displayed.

A solution is to reduce the viewer registry to only the first available viewer:

```
>>> PIL.ImageShow._viewers = [ PIL.ImageShow._viewers[0] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

it is able to specify the viewer as `command` argument to the `show` method, e.g.

> > > img.show(command='feh')

Comment: Hmm, that has no effect.  Still get display and  mirage, and not, say, gimp if I give that as a command.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, it is a problem in PIL. You can change the PIL code in the following way:

In the file ImageShow.py replace

```
return "start /wait %s && del /f %s" % (file,file)
```

with

```
return "start /wait %s && del /wait /f %s" % (file,file)
```