# Using PIL to show resized image opens two windows

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I would like to display an image fullscreen using the Python Imaging library. I am working on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, Python 2.7, and using ImageMagick to display the image. Running the following code works as expected:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("sampleImage.png")
im.show()
```

[Normal functioning Image.show()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP6Hx.png)

However, if I try to resize the image, two windows are displayed, one of which I think is an Icon.

```
from screeninfo import get_monitors

m = get_monitors()
width = m[0].width
height = m[0].height

im = im.resize((width, height))
im.show()
```

[Resized Image.show() displays two images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buVRj.png)

I have tried saving the resized image and then opening it again, but I get the same results. The screeninfo package comes from [here](https://pypi.org/project/screeninfo/). When trying to find similar posts, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034659/pils-image-show-brings-up-two-different-viewers), but I checked `PIL.ImageShow._viewers` and I only have one viewer. The solutions shown there may also be old, since ImageShow.py did not seem to have the same issues as mentioned in the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the second window only appears if the image is resized to larger than the screen. If the width and height are set to the screen resolution, this does not take into account the menu bar and task bar, so the window ends up larger than the screen.

To work around this, I did `im = im.resize((width, int(0.95*height)))`